# setting up heap in memory for ARM embedded system

Tags: gcc, malloc, heap-memory, stm32, cortex-m

i am thinking of setting up a memory area in my STM32L151 (Cortex M3) for heap to be used in malloc().

I am using the GNU ARM toolchain and newlib.

I know how to set up the stack in the linker script, assign the stack address to SP... and that the ARM uC can access the stack via the stack pointer, SP.

My question is :how does GNU GCC compiler knows where is the heap address?
I can set up the heap in the linker script like how i does for the stack.. But how do i pass the heap address information to the GCC compiler?

Thank you very much.

Comment: 1) malloc on a system like that is a bad idea...2) newlib has a libcfunc.c and a system something file that are all of the system interfaces including malloc, look there to figure out how to tell newlib where your heap is.  the compiler cares not and knows not malloc is a C library thing not a compiler thing.

Comment: @old_timer, unfortunately there are a number of standard functions within newlib that use malloc/free (i.e. some of the things like dtoa, itoa, called from vsnprint, also localtime, and more).  So if you're going to use any of those you will need at least a small heap.

Comment: @CraigB that is the point, this is bare metal, functions like those should be avoided on a platform like this.  There is no place for malloc in a system like this nor any function that relies on it.  If you need an operating system or cannot live without system calls then find an appropriate platform.  They provide little value on a platform like this, easily replaced with something sensible.

Comment: This is quite a while later, but @old_timer I get what you're saying. We use a number of different very capable STM32 MCUs across our many products running very sophisticated firmware with all kinds of capabilities.  So it's not just a "bare metal" situation for many people.  The question really is whether you want to leverage all the quality, tested code that newlib offers or write all your own libs and test and support them.  Newlib for us requires a 512 byte heap.  ...and it basically reuses the same memory block over and over without mallocing/freeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did something similar on a cortex-m3 platform at a previous job, also using new lib.  I went about it by implementing a custom `_sbrk()/_sbrk_r()` function, which `malloc()` uses.  You would create a static array as large as you need for the heap, and your `_sbrk()/_sbrk_r()` function would adjust within that.

For example (only minimal error checking, for clarity):

```
static char mem_array[MAX_HEAP_SIZE];
static char *_cur_brk = mem_array;
void *_sbrk_r(struct _reent *reent, ptrdiff_t diff)
{
    char *_old_brk = _cur_brk;
    if (_cur_brk + diff > MAX_HEAP_SIZE) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return (void *)-1;
    }
    _cur_brk += diff;
    return _old_brk;
}
```